# Choose correct user-name-attribute claim at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, adfs

I'm trying to authenticate using multiple identity providers behind ADFS.
The problem is that the different identity providers issue tokens with different claims to be used as user-name-attribute.

So instead of configuring *spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.name.user-name-attribute* statically for the adfs client i need to pick the right claim depending on the identity provider the user picked or was redirected to through ADFS.

Is there any way to choose the claim at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Each IDP is a CP and each application is an RP.

So on the CP side, map each IDP's user-name-attribute to a temp-user-name-attribute claim.

On the RP side, map temp-user-name-attribute claim to whatever claim the RP expects.

Remember to pass-through the temp-user-name-attribute claim.

No, there is no way to choose the claim at runtime.